# Associate for each vertice a random vector and a random vector using netwkorx random graph generation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, graph-theory

l'm newbie to random graph generation in python.

l discovered that networks library allows to do that.

However, l would like to generate random graphs where we associate for each vertice a random color and a random vector of size 200.

Here is what l tried to make the graph

```
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


G = nx.grid_2d_graph(7, 7)  


nx.write_adjlist(G, sys.stdout.buffer)  # write adjacency list to screen
# write edgelist to grid.edgelist

nx. write_edgelist(G, path="grid.edgelist", delimiter=":")

# read edgelist from grid.edgelist

H = nx.read_edgelist(path="grid.edgelist", delimiter=":")

nx.draw(H)
plt.show()
```

However, all the vertices have the same color and don't have any random vector.

What l would like to get is from the generated graph :
we associate a random color for each vertice and a random vector.

Hoc can l do that ?

Here is the generated graph :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: @Drubio, thanks for your edit

Comment: The colours are easy. Can you be more specific about the random vectors? Do you just need a list of vectors, do they need to be plotted, how long, etc. ?

Comment: @ThomasKühn, l'm looking to make different graphs  : 1) line graph with a variable number of nodes 2) triangle  graph with a variable number of nodes 3) square and rectangle graph with a variable number of nodes  4) tree graph  with a variable number of nodes 5) bipartite graph wit a variable number of nodes . Each node is associated with a random vector of dim (224,224,3) which is generated randomly ( random image) and the vectors are not needed to be plotted. The color of each node represent the color of the max intensity of the random RGB image . Hope it's more clear